# Create configmaps from files recursively

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

I have multiple configuration files in two directories. For example,

- conf.d/parentconf1.conf
- con.d/node1/child1.conf
- conf.d/node2/child2.conf

I need to mount these configuration files in the same directory structure to kubernetes pod using `ConfigMap`.

Tried using the

```
kubectl create configmap --from-file=./conf.d --from-file=./conf.d/node1/child1.conf --from-file=./conf.d/node2/child2.conf.
```

Config map created, as expected, cannot express the nested directory structure.

Is it possible to create ConfigMap recursively from folders and still retain the folder structure in the name of the key entry for the ConfigMap - since the intention is to mount these ConfigMaps into pods?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, reflecting directory structure in configmap is not supported currently. Workaround is to express directory hierarchy like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
   name: testconfig
data:
  file1: |
    This is file1
  file2: |
    This is file2 in subdir directory
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: testpod
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
    - name: test-container
      image: gcr.io/google_containers/busybox
      command: [ "/bin/sh","-c", "sleep 1000" ]
      volumeMounts:
      - name: config-volume
        mountPath: /etc/config
  volumes:
    - name: config-volume
      configMap:
        name: testconfig
        items:
        - key: file2
          path: subdir/file2
        - key: file1
          path: file1
```

Comment: These configuration files are multi-pipline configuration files for logstash. So, there will be 10-12 files already (bound to grow). Currently, I used the approach to mount the nested directory to a different config-map using kubectl. Going with the work-around.

Comment: Are there a way to mount one additional nested file in the subdir, but the rest of files - as a first-level mount? I have 1 file in a subdirectory and a bunch of them on the first level, so it's not really convenient to list all the files.

Answer (score 13):

An automatable workaround: tar your files, map the tar configmap volume file in /tmp, and untar it at the start of the container.

Create the tar:

```
tar -cvf conf-d.tar ./conf.d
kubectl create configmap conf-d --from-file=conf-d.tar
rm conf-d.tar
```

and in your pod.yml, add the tar -xf before your command, or before your default image command:

```
    command: [ "/bin/sh","-c", "tar -xf /tmp/conf-d.tar -C /etc/ && sleep 1000" ]
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /tmp/conf-d.tar
        name: nginx-config-volume
        subPath: conf-d.tar
```

Answer (score 5):

When writing templates for Helm charts the [built-in tooling](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/#glob-patterns) can be used to create a config map or secret with all files in a directory.

Directory structure:

```
test
├── bar
│   └── init.sh
├── foo
│   ├── some.sh
│   └── thing.sh
└── README
```

Helm config map template:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
data:
  {{- $files := .Files }}
  {{- range $path, $_ := .Files.Glob "test/**" }}
  {{ $path | replace "/" "." }}: |
{{ $files.Get $path | indent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
```

Result:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: my-configmap
data:
  test.bar.init.sh: |
    echo foo
  test.foo.some.sh: |
    echo foo
  test.foo.thing.sh: |
    echo foo
  test.README: |
    # My title
```

Tested with helm `3.7.1`